# Cannot enable Wordpress Network - 'MULTISITE' already defined and false

Tags: multisite, network-admin, constants

In wp-config.php I have this code:

```
var_dump(defined('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE'));  // false
var_dump(defined('MULTISITE'));           // true
var_dump(defined('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL'));   // false

define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
var_dump(WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE);             // true
define('MULTISITE', true);
var_dump(MULTISITE);                      // false
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
var_dump(SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL);              // true
```

`MULTISITE` constant is already defined with `false` before wp-confing.php. I searched with `grep` and it's defined only in `./wp-admin/includes/network.php` as `define('MULTISITE', true);`.

How to make it true? I tried on local Laradock instance and shared hosting. In both cases result is the same.

**EDIT (new info)**

Results of running `grep -Rn MULTISITE ./ | grep define | grep -v defined`

```
./wp-config.php:118:define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
./wp-config.php:121:define('MULTISITE', true);
./wp-settings.php:125:  define( 'MULTISITE', false );
./wp-admin/includes/network.php:439:define('MULTISITE', true);
```

After enabling debugging in wp-config.php with `define('WP_DEBUG', true);` I am getting this notice in the admin area:

```
Notice: Constant MULTISITE already defined in /wordpress/wp-config.php on line 120
```

**EDIT (solution)**

My bad, I put define() calls below require_once for wp-settings.php in wp-config.

Comment: Are you certain you're looking at all includes? What does `grep -Rn MULTISITE ./ | grep define | grep -v defined` report?

Comment: @Gray I updated my question.

Comment: Glad to see you were able to get things sorted!

Comment: Had the same problem, luckily I found your question! Thanks